# Generate a Certificate Signing Request for ssl using java program

Tags: java, csr

I want to write a program that can generate **Certificate Signing Request** with all information like domain name, country name, state organisation etc. I know to how to generate it with **open-ssl** but I want to generate it with only **java program**. How can I do this?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe `jwt` is what you are looking?

Comment: No, I want to create ssl certificate and for that I want to make a CSR with using any command line

Answer (score 2):

Bouncy castle provides all the tools you need to do that.

Here is the code to generate a CSR:

```
    PrivateKey priKey = entry.getPrivateKey(keystore, pwd);
    PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder p10Builder
            = new JcaPKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(
                    cert.getSubjectX500Principal(), cert.getPublicKey());
    JcaContentSignerBuilder csBuilder = new JcaContentSignerBuilder(cert.getSigAlgName());
    ContentSigner signer = csBuilder.build(priKey);
    PKCS10CertificationRequest csr = p10Builder.build(signer);
    try (OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(stream, "UTF-8");
            JcaPEMWriter out = new JcaPEMWriter(writer)) {
        out.writeObject(csr);
    }
```